# Getting Error while trying to use stylist on my app in yew

Tags: rust, yew

this is my code in `Yew`

```rust
use yew::prelude::*;
use gloo::console::*;
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};
use stylist::{yew::styled_component, style};

const STYLE_FILE: &str = include_str!("main.css");

#[styled_component(App)]
pub fn app() -> Html {
    let stylesheet = Style::new(STYLE_FILE).unwrap();

    html! {
        <>
        <h1 class={stylesheet}>{"Hello World"}</h1>
        if obj.username == "a" {
            <p>{"a"}</p>
        } else {
            <p>{"b"}</p>
        }
        </>
    }
}
```

I'm getting error here at `#[styled_component(App)]`.

It says:

```
error: linking with cc failed: exit status: 1

error: could not compile `stylist-macros` (lib) due to previous error
2023-06-13T23:51:37.351135Z ERROR \u274c error
error from HTML pipeline
```

My architecture is arm64 (M1 chip) Ubuntu via UTM.
I'm serving my app via `trunk serve`.
And my `stylist` crate looks like this: `stylist = {version = "0.10.0", features = ["yew"]}`

Answer (score 0):

you seem to be using `style`. You should import `Style`

```rs
use yew::prelude::*;
use gloo::console::*;
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};
use stylist::{yew::styled_component, Style};

const STYLE_FILE: &str = include_str!("main.css");

#[styled_component(App)]
pub fn app() -> Html {
    let stylesheet = Style::new(STYLE_FILE).unwrap();

    html! {
        <>
        <h1 class={stylesheet}>{"Hello World"}</h1>
        if obj.username == "a" {
            <p>{"a"}</p>
        } else {
            <p>{"b"}</p>
        }
        </>
    }
}
```